# How to use multiple conditions with AddOrUpdate to determine if the db should add the model or update?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So what I want to do is add or update a user depending on if that user already exist inside my seed method.

I want the condition to be if the user with the first name and last name already exist but adding a && doesn't seem to work.

```
foreach (User user in users)
{
    context.users.AddOrUpdate(r => r.FirstName *&& r => r.LastName*, user);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Becouse you need to aggregate your properties to one object (lets say `string` -- `varchar` :) )

```
.AddOrUpdate(r => r.FirstName + r.LastName);
```

**Edit:**
I dont try it, but *i hope* it will be translated to *something like*

```
UPDATE a SET a.* = #b.* FROM #b INNER JOIN a ON 
  a.FirstName + a.LastName = #b.FirstName + #b.LastName;
INSERT INTO a (*) VALUES (*) LEFT JOIN #b ON 
  a.FirstName + a.LastName = #b.FirstName + #b.LastName where a.* = null;
```

so yes, there is concating of , but why not (btw that query is possibly wrong, i wrote it from memory) 
or with some token, so you dont update "Jon Snow" when entering "JonS now"

```
.AddOrUpdate(r => r.FirstName + "#:)" + r.LastName);
```

Dont forget to add index ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response but this will not work because this just concats two different properties, I need to compare each of these separately.

Comment: Yeah, `where a.FirstName = #b.FirstName && a.LastName = #b.LastName` would be much better, but i am not sure if EF know this... Lets hope for another answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just tackle with this problem. So I wanted to share my code. Use "Anonymous Type" to get this right.

```
foreach (User user in users)
{
    context.users.AddOrUpdate(r => new{ r.FirstName , r.LastName} , user);
}
```